# How Xtext knows that entity is referred by ID rule here?

Tags: grammar, xtext

In Xtext 15 minutes tutorial ([here](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#_1)) the `Entity` rule is defined as follows

```
Entity:
  'entity' name = ID ('extends' superType = [Entity])? '{'
     features += Feature*
  '}'
;
```

which means that after word "extends" parser should expect reference to (another) entity. How is it set that actually here should be used `ID` rule? What if I have no `ID` rule in my grammar?

Answer (score 2):

The cross references in `superType = [Entity]` is a shorthand notation for `superType = [Entity|ID]`. If you use `superType = [Entity|STRING]`, references will be based on the concrete syntax of the terminal rule STRING.

Comment: So if I have my own rule `MyRule1` for identifiers then I should write `superType=[Entity|MyRule1]`?

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget to register a value converter for your terminal / data type rule.